# php shell_exec() interpolation

Tags: php, shell-exec

I have a php script that builds a dynamic command string (calls a perl script), then executes the command, like this:

```
    $cmd_string = "perl $pushFile";
    foreach($cmd_args AS $argName => $arg){
        $cmd_string .= ' --' . $argName . '="' . $arg . '"';
    }
    $output = shell_exec('export PERL5LIB=/mnt/path/to/custom:$PERL5LIB  && ' . $cmd_string . ' 2>&1');
```

I am getting failures that I think are being caused by interpolation of some of the arguments. For example is one of the arguments is '246+8GT>-', it gets turned into '246 8GT ' and an error that the string is unterminated. But, if I print_r $cmd_string to the screen and execute it via command line, or copy/paste it into the $cmd_string variable, it executes properly. I am stumped. How can I make sure these arguments are being passed properly? I tried this:

```
    $output = shell_exec('export PERL5LIB=/mnt/path/to/custom:$PERL5LIB  && ' . escapeshellcmd($cmd_string) . ' 2>&1');
```

but get the same result. Help?

Answer (score 0):

You are escaping the comamand string, after it has been built.

Try this:

```
$cmd_string = "perl $pushFile";
foreach($cmd_args AS $argName => $arg){
    $cmd_string .= ' --' . $argName . '="' . escapeshellarg($arg) . '"';
}
$output = shell_exec('export PERL5LIB=/mnt/path/to/custom:$PERL5LIB  && ' . $cmd_string . ' 2>&1');
```